# How does an external bias change the built-in voltage?

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

First things first, barrier potential/height is different than the built-in voltage of a diode. The built-in voltage is a constant. The external bias changes the barrier height. The barrier height equals the built-in voltage when the external bias is 0.

Now, suppose the built-in voltage is 0.7V and the external bias is 0.5V. What will be the resulting barrier potential/height? Is there any equation for this?

Comment: What's wrong with just reading a good "microelectronics" book? All of this stuff is discussed. Better, some of the books on the topic are very, very accessible. Not all that hard to read, actually. You don't need to be in a class or have a teacher or anything. The stuff just 'spills out' and makes a lot of sense. You'll learn about the mass-action law and the Einstein relationship, for example. It's really pretty easy stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm in high school and I don't have too much time.

Comment: Well, I just worked from 7AM to 1AM (yes, less than six hours sleep) for a period of over ten days completing work (got it done on time!) I still take time to read. I operate a 24/7 365 days a year operation. It is *always* busy here. I don't make such excuses. And I didn't when I was your age, either. Worked hard. It's part of how I gained the opportunities I was lucky enough to get. Finally, there's no such thing as "spoon fed" knowledge. If there was a pill for it, there'd be some really rich people selling them to you.

Comment: Damn. I guess I am being too easy on myself then. Could you recommend me a book?

Comment: One of them that I like is old, but often the older books are easier to read since they don't presume as much prior training. It's from Jacob Millman and it is called "Microelectronics: Digital and Analog Circuits and Systems," dated 1979. It should be VERY cheap to get. Most of what's in there is useful, today. Also, newer editions may be revamped and less useful. For example, Douglas Comer (I have worked with him) wrote a book on XINU. The first version is STELLAR. The later editions? Not as worth having. Sometimes the earlier editions are better, if you are self-educating.

Comment: That question is not a useful hypothetical one as it does not exist.  If you want some useful reading on practical applications of applied electronics , I pulled this reference from my profile http://ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/socratic/model/index.html. I haven’t read it because I already have that experience, but thought it might be useful for some.

Comment: For example one module on diodes and C++ and Python etc http://ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/socratic/model/mod_pn.pdf then how to model a diode in C++ then jumping right into Valence levels …